# android image to .net webservice

Tags: android, .net, web-services, image, arrays

I am retrieving an image from my SQLite table and converting it to a byte array using this code :

```
byte[] imageByteArray = cImage.getBlob(cImage.getColumnIndex("ImageData"));
```

which works fine (I have proven this by decoding it back to the original image like this :

```
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

The problem I have is I need to serialise the image data and send it via .net web services, then decode it at the other end.

I am using this code to encode the byte[] to a Base64 string :

```
String sImageData = Base64.encode(imageByteArray);
```

Then adding it as a property to my service call.

The call takes a while to complete which indicates it is sending the data - although I get the exception "Value cannot be null" when I do this in the web service :

```
byte[] baImageData = Convert.FromBase64String(sImageData);
```

I'm not sure how I can debug this any further - am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine, but if you send a long picture, it crash.

in Android:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL="http://XXX.XX.113.79/Sincro_Mobile/Sincro.asmx";
ws_btn_Enviar_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String METHOD_NAME = "FOTO_and";
                final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/FOTO_and";

                ws_resultado.setText("");
                request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                Bitmap imagen_decodificar = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+
                        "/"+Globales.fotos_sgi+"/tomafoto1_resize_70.jpg");   
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();     
                imagen_decodificar.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);     
                byte[] imagebyte = out.toByteArray(); 
                String strBase64 = Base64.encodeBytes(imagebyte); 
                request.addProperty("user", "ap"); 
                request.addProperty("pass", "qwerty"); 
                request.addProperty("x", contrasena); 
                request.addProperty("buffer",strBase64);
                request.addProperty("filename","primer_foto.jpg");
                //request.addProperty("Fecha_MOVIMIENTOS_y_FOTOS",dia_de_hoy.toString());
                envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true; //se asigna true para el caso de que el WS sea de dotNet
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                try {
                    transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    ws_resultado.setText(resultsRequestSOAP.toString()) ;
                    } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    ws_resultado.setText(e.toString());;
                    }
                 catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                     ws_resultado.setText(e.toString());;
                    }

              }
        });
```

In .net Webservice:

```
 <WebMethod()> Public Function FOTO_and(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String, _
    ByVal x As String, ByVal buffer As Byte(), ByVal filename As String) As String

        Dim Log As String = Validacion_User_EMEI(user, pass, x)

        If Log <> Estados_Sincro.OK Then
            Return Log
        End If

        '--VERIFICA QUE EXISTA LA CARPETA PARA ALMACENAR LA FOTO

        Dim Path_Fotos As String

        Path_Fotos = AppSettings.GetValues("Fotos")(0) + Now.ToString("yyMMdd")
        If Directory.Exists(Path_Fotos) = False Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path_Fotos)
        End If

        '---VERIFICA QUE LA FOTO NO EXISTA

        If File.Exists(Path_Fotos + "\" + filename) Then
            Kill(Path_Fotos + "\" + filename)
        End If

        '--GUARDA LA FOTO

        Dim binWriter As New BinaryWriter(File.Open(Path_Fotos + "\" + filename, _
        FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        binWriter.Write(buffer)
        binWriter.Close()

        Return Estados_Sincro.OK

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The android part looks fine to me.